# jquery-ui Droppable: Drop function not being called

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, droppable, jquery-ui-droppable

I am working on a music library application, in which I am looking to implement playlists where you can drag and drop tracks to add them to a playlist.

Right now, I am using these jquery calls to make my playlist-row's droppable and my track-rows draggable. Here is the

```
$(".playlist-row").droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ){
        console.log("dropped");
    }
});

$(".track-row").draggable({ opacity: 0.7, helper: "clone"});
```

I have verified that this jquery runs properly, as my track-rows have these classes: "track-row ng-scope ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" and my playlist-rows have these classes: "playlist-row ng-binding ui-droppable"

The rows are definitely draggable, but when I drag them to the playlist-row and release my mouse, nothing happens. No drop event is fired, and there's no console log. I have yet to find any indication about why this would be happening.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle

Comment: If you can't provide a fiddle, please include the relevant html in your question.